# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted

Tags: java, javamail

Mi problema es tal como dice el titulo, pero solo se presenta cuando trato de enviar un correo a una direccion distinta, en primer lugar como objeto de prueba utilice mi correo como remitente y receptor, pero a la hora de utilizar un receptor distinto me lanza dicho error.

Tengo la opcion de permitir apps menos seguras activada.

El problema no esta en que la otra cuenta tenga verificacion de dos pasos activada ya que ninguna de las cuenta lo tiene activo.

```
private void envia_correo(String destino) throws MessagingException{
    
    Properties propiedad = new Properties();
    propiedad.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
    propiedad.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    propiedad.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", port);
    propiedad.setProperty("mail.smtp,auth", "true");

    Session sesion = Session.getDefaultInstance(propiedad);
    MimeMessage mensaje = new MimeMessage(sesion);

    try {
        mensaje.setFrom(new InternetAddress(destinatario));
        mensaje.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(destino));
        mensaje.setSubject("Codigo Restablecimiento de Contraseña");
        mensaje.setText(texto,"utf-8","html");

        Transport transportar = sesion.getTransport("smtp");
        transportar.connect(destinatario, clave);
        transportar.sendMessage(mensaje, mensaje.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        transportar.close();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Listo, revise su correo");

    } catch (AddressException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Panel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}//FIN METODO ENVIA
```

[image: Correo envia correctamente]

Aqui les dejo el error completo.

```
ene. 19, 2021 9:53:09 P. M. JDialog.Login jButton_resetActionPerformed
```

SEVERE: null
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials w66sm107674vkb.50 - gsmtp

```
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:965)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:876)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:780)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:267)
at JDialog.Login.envia_correo(Login.java:210)
at JDialog.Login.olvido_contrasena(Login.java:302)
at JDialog.Login.jButton_resetActionPerformed(Login.java:374)
at JDialog.Login.access$200(Login.java:29)
at JDialog.Login$3.actionPerformed(Login.java:104)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6614)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6379)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4990)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4919)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4548)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4489)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2769)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Si me pueden ayudar seria genial gracias por adelantado

Comment: ¿Y ya revisaste https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials ? ¿Intentaste lo que dice ahí?

Comment: En el código no veo que uses las propiedades `mail.smtp.user` y `mail.smtp.clave` que son para autenticarte.

Comment: Lo probare pero no entiendo entonces si es a mi correo porque no da error.
Lo de google esta todo en orden.

Comment: Pues como comente el error fue una confucion en cuanto a lo de **mail.smtp.user** y **mail.smtp.clave** hago la identificacion en esta parte **transportar.connect(destinatario, clave);** @RobertoEMoran de todas formas gracias a ti note el error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues el problema era mio, una pequeña confucion a la hora de escribir las variables estaba pasando el campo de el correo de destino tanto como para el destino como para quien envia, una pequeña confucion de nombres asi que le cambie el nombre para que no pase nueva vez y a su vez gane XP. :p

Answer (score 0):

Si talvéz tienen el error  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials w66sm107674vkb.50 - gsmtp, se tiene que realizar los siguientes pasos:

1. Activar el doble factor de autentiticación en https://myaccount.google.com/u/2/security
2. Generar un nuevo password en la opción **Contraseña de Aplicaciones**, el cual generará una clave de 16 caracteres, y será ésta la que deben utilizar en sus aplicaciones para enviar correo con Gmail.

[image: Generar Contraseña Aplicación]